# DC-DC power supply module help needed

Tags: power, dc, switch-mode-power-supply

I have purchased this little brick (link below) that I though would allow me to input for example 12V DC and output a lower output voltage, for example 5V DC, but I'm now testing it and it seems to work the other way around: it only gives me an output of 12V or MORE... I don't have much experience in electronics so I don't know if this is how its supposed to be, or if the brick is bad... 
any help?

the thing: http://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00GWFEIVE?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00

by the way, this is a switched power supply, right? (not linear)

Comment: Me no hablo espanol, but there's a magic phrase in the description (which maybe you should have read before buying?): "Nota: El modo step-up"...

Comment: Changing the "es" to "ca" yields "Adjustable LED Digital Step Up Power Boost Module".

Comment: thanks Ignacio, I didnt knew that little trick... the english version is much clearer about the mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltaje de entrada: 3-35V Corriente de entrada: 9A (Max) Voltaje de salida: 3.5-35V (Nota: El modo step-up,

This says: Input voltage: 3-35V Input current: 9A (Max) Output voltage: 3.5-35V (Note: The mode step-up,

So this is a step up not step down regulator module. It is working as it should. You need a step down regulator to get less voltage out than you put in.

The one review of it also mentions using it to power a 12V fan from 5V usb, which is a step up (5V to 12V) application. There is nothing on the page I found that implies it can step down voltages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did read the "el modo step-up" thing but the way its redacted in spanish made me thing it could be used both ways.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't speak much spanish so I'm just direct translating the words. I usually use adafruit or pololu for small modules like this, or ebay with a good seller. You just want to make sure it says step-down somewhere. It will specify step-up/step-down if it does both.